# Validate username/password against Azure AD without a UI?

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory

How can I validate a username/password against Azure AD without showing a UI? I have an autonomous processes running (think Windows Service or scheduled task) where the username and password are stored in a configuration table.

Since there is no "user at the wheel" so to speak, we can't use the normal method that shows the Azure login page (https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}).

Answer (score 2):

**1. Just make it work, no changes approach (Not Recommended)**

You can try to get a token using Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant. (ROPC might be the least secure among all the different grants supported and brings potential attack risks. Also note that ROPC doesn't work with MFA and has issues with federated authentication users or may not work in those cases at all)

I don't think there is any method/endpoint available to specifically **validate the username/password**, but the workaround is if either username or password is incorrect, you will get an exception from the token endpoint when using ROPC, otherwise you get back a valid token which means credentials are good.

You can read about how to get a token using ROPC here:
[Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant in Azure AD OAuth](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/)

---

**2. Suggested Approach, some changes required (Recommended)**

This might feel a little inconvenient at beginning, but it will be well worth the effort from a security standpoint. Note that this approach as well as the first one will meet your requirement of not going through normal login page as well.

> Since there is no "user at the wheel" so to speak, we can't use the
>   normal method that shows the Azure login page
>   (https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}).

As you mention that the autonomous process is like a Windows Service or Scheduled task, from Azure AD and OAuth 2.0 perspective your process looks like a **Daemon** service. So instead of using a username/password credentials directly from configuration, which violates security best practices, you should be looking at using Client Credentials Grant. It's strongly advised NOT to collect/manage/store end user credentials (or create old world Service Accounts) directly in your applications.

You can read about it in detail here: [**OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant with Azure AD**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

Also visit this documentation for all Azure AD app types and scenarios, specifically those listed for Daemon apps. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-types)

To put it very briefly, your process gets represented by a registered application in Azure AD and for credentials part you can use:

a. Client ID + Client Secret Key (provided by Azure AD specifically for your application. you can generate more than one secret keys for different purposes with different expiration etc.). [Sample C# code with Client Secret](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon)

b. Client ID + Certificate (pass a JWT that you need to create and sign with the certificate you registered as credentials for your application). [Sample C# code with Certificate](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential)

---